# How to use SQLite's UPSERT (or ON CONFLICT) with flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to update my SQLite DB with data provided by an external API and I don't want to check every time for any conflicts by myself, instead, I want to take advantage of `UPSERT` statement. SQLAlchemy documentation for version 1.4 (still in beta but that's ok) shows that [this is possible](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html?highlight=conflict#insert-on-conflict-upsert). But I don't know how to get this to work with flask_sqlalchemy.

I've also tried to include `sqlite_on_conflict='IGNORE'` in constraint definitions (as mentioned in SQLAlchemy docs for version 1.3 [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html?highlight=conflict#on-conflict-support-for-constraints)):

```py
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ('id', 'other_id'),
            ('other_table.id', 'other_table.other_id')
            sqlite_on_conflict='IGNORE'
        ),
    )
    # ...
```

I then verified SQL output with `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` set to `True` and it didn't work at all...

I tried with both 1.3 and 1.4 SQLAlchemy versions.

Comment: Quoting the sqlite docs: "The ON CONFLICT clause applies to UNIQUE, NOT NULL, CHECK, and PRIMARY KEY constraints. The ON CONFLICT algorithm does not apply to FOREIGN KEY constraints.". That makes me believe the problem is not sqlalchemy but rather the feature you want is not supported by sqlite. Could you try it with a UniqueConstraint?

Comment: I should've mentioned that those foreign keys are also primary keys, but anyway, I've managed to solve the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/droustchev/5145cb1fcbf0cf365229) (credits for [droustchev](https://github.com/droustchev)) which I slightly [edited](https://gist.github.com/8ru73u5/1950eeaa59664145030fef21f8e139ca). It's a bit messy but it works:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql import Insert


@compiles(Insert, 'sqlite')
def suffix_insert(insert, compiler, **kwargs):
    stmt = compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kwargs)
    if insert.dialect_kwargs.get('sqlite_on_conflict_do_nothing'):
        stmt += ' ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING'
    return stmt


Insert.argument_for('sqlite', 'on_conflict_do_nothing', False)
```

Just include this code in your `models.py` file (or whatever filename you have) and then you can write:

```py
some_random_values = [
  {'id': 1, 'some_column': 'asadsadad'},
  {'id': 2, 'some_column': 'dsawaefds'}
]

stmt = db.insert(MyModel, sqlite_on_conflict_do_nothing=True).values(some_random_values)
db.session.execute(stmt)
```

This should do the trick.